# How to list colnames by row when data >0

Tags: r

Hi i have an excel doc (100 columns, 350 rows) with data values from 0-10000. I've been trying to get  a list of which columns contain values >0. I've been tinkering with apply but cant get anything to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
e.g       Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
    row 1  1     2     0     0      
    row 2  0     1    1      0
    row 3  2     0    0      0

    row 1 col1 col2
    row 2 col2 col3 
    row 3 col1'
```

Comment: Easy was to see this is `colSums(data)`

Comment: @Adii_ - but that doesn't tell you that there is a zero in row 2, column 1

Comment: @RichardScriven as I understood the question, the goal is to find columns that contains not only 0's (colSum > 0). Another advice will be read the file with 0's as NA'a.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `names` after first converting the data to a logical matrix.  If `df` is your original data,

```
apply(df > 0, 1, function(x) names(which(x)))
# $`row 1`
# [1] "Col1" "Col2"
#
# $`row 2`
# [1] "Col2" "Col3"
#
# $`row 3`
# [1] "Col1"
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, knew there was something i was missing, hadn't converted to matrix. You've saved me a lot of time, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this , is to create a matrix of names and fiter using the efficient matrix index sub-setting  to get only names fulfilling certain condition.

```
nn = matrix(rep(names(dat),nrow(dat)),nrow(dat),byrow=TRUE)
nn
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
[1,] "Col1" "Col2" "Col3" "Col4"
[2,] "Col1" "Col2" "Col3" "Col4"
[3,] "Col1" "Col2" "Col3" "Col4"
```

Now you get the index of positive values using `which`:

```
id <- which(dat>0,arr.ind = TRUE)
   row col
row1   1   1
row3   3   1
row1   1   2
row2   2   2
row2   2   3
```

You can subset nn using id , something like `nn[id]` but since you want to group result by row here I am using `by`:

```
by(id,id[,'row'],FUN=function(i)nn[as.matrix(i)])

NDICES: 1
[1] "Col1" "Col2"
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
INDICES: 2
[1] "Col2" "Col3"
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
INDICES: 3
[1] "Col1"
```